# html5Loader, center animation

Tags: javascript, center, preloader, window-resize

I use HTML5Loader in order to preload pictures before displaying the website interface.
This script displays a centered circular loader in the meantime.
The problem is that the loader is centered alright but doesn't adapt if the window browser is stretched vertically or horizontally during the loading.
This loader has a script on its own and, for the life of me, I don't know how to refresh it during a window resize.

Here is the script part that handles the display of the circular loader:

```
(function($) {
  'use strict';
  $.fn.extend({
    LoaderAnimation: function(customOptions) {
      var defaults = {},
          $container = $(this),
          options = $.extend(defaults, customOptions),
          self = this;

      /* PUBLIC VAR Configuration */
      var lineWidth = options.lineWidth,
          color = options.color,
          glowColor = options.glowColor,
          radius = options.radius,
          font = options.font;

      this.currentPercentage = 0;

      /* PRIVATE VAR */
      var $window = $(window),
          PI = Math.PI,
          startAngle = 1.5 * PI,
          endAngle = 0,
          supportsCanvas = !!document.createElement('canvas').getContext,
          canvasWidth = $('body').width(),
          canvasHeight = $('body').height(),
          $canvas, $fallbackHtml, ctx;

      /* PRIVATE METHODS */

      /* Used as fallback for the old browsers */

      var fallback = function() {
        $fallbackHtml.text((self.currentPercentage | 0) + "%");
      };

      /* Clear the canvas during each frame of the animation */

      var clear = function() {
        if (supportsCanvas)
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        return true;
      };

      /* Draw on the canvas the animation */

      var draw = function() {
        var alphaPercentage = (2 / 100) * self.currentPercentage,
          positionX = canvasWidth / 2-15,
          positionY = canvasHeight / 2;

        endAngle = (alphaPercentage * PI) + startAngle;

        clear();
        ctx.restore();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.font = font;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.fillText((self.currentPercentage | 0) + "%", positionX, positionY);
        ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        if (glowColor) {
          ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
          ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
          ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
          ctx.shadowColor = glowColor;
        }
        ctx.arc(positionX, positionY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.save();
      };

      /* Check if the precentage is equal to 100% to remove the preloader*/

      var onAnimationEnd = function() {
        if (self.currentPercentage === 100) {
          $container.delay(1000).fadeOut(function() {
            $container.remove();
            if (typeof options.onComplete === "function")
              options.onComplete();
          });
          $window.off("resize.preloader");
        }
      };

      /* Center the canvas on window resize */

      var centerLoader = function() {
        canvasWidth = $('body').width()-13;
        canvasHeight =$('body').height();
        if (supportsCanvas) {
          $canvas[0].width = canvasWidth;
          $canvas[0].height = canvasHeight;
        }
        $container.width(canvasWidth);
        $container.height(canvasHeight);
      };


      /* PUBLIC METHODS */

      self.init = function() {
        if (supportsCanvas) {
          $canvas = $("<canvas>");
          $container.append($canvas);
          ctx = $canvas[0].getContext('2d');
        } else {
          $fallbackHtml = $("<i class='fallback'></i>");
          $container.append($fallbackHtml);

        }
        centerLoader();
        $window.on("resize.preloader", centerLoader);
      };
      self.update = function(prercentage) {

        $.Animation(self, {
          currentPercentage: prercentage
        }, {
          duration: 3000
        })
          .stop(true, false)
          .progress(function() {
            if (supportsCanvas)
              draw();
            else
              fallback();
          })
          .done(onAnimationEnd);
      };

      this.init();

      return this;
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Obviously, it has to do with the "canvasWidth" and "canvasHeight" which dictate the value of the "positionX" and the "positionY" variables but those are defined according to the body size when the animation starts.
I don't see how I can refresh those values during the animation without resetting the animation.
Normally, I would use a "$(window).resize" and fire a function there to refresh the values but even though I would know which function to fire up, it would just reset the whole thing while I want the load percentage to remain accurate, even though the window is resized.

What I want is pretty simple and should have been easily handled by css: center horizontally and vertically the circular loader at all times.

I tried to change this:

```
$window.on("resize.preloader", centerLoader);
```

with:

```
$(window).resize(function(e) {centerLoader();});
```

With no success.
The resize function, even the built in one, never seems to fire up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not redraw the loader again from the last point he stops with the new x & y ?

Comment: Thank you Yochai. How would I do that?